# .NET 4 - Satellite assembly (language resources) DLL loading change in CLR / .NET / ASP.NET 4

Tags: .net, clr, satellite-assembly

Does anybody know if loading of satellite assemblies has changed in .NET/CLR/ASP.NET 4.0?

It seems like now the GetString operation on resources is making a call to first check if the assembly is loaded in en-US, en-GB, en-AU, etc, and then loading from the en directory.

Is this a by design change? This is causing huge performance regressions for us.

Answer (score 2):

See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526836/wpf-appdomain-assemblyresolve-being-called-when-it-shouldnt